How to write logs via File Exporter in non OTLP JSON format
I would like to export logs to a file using OpenTelemetry Collector File Exporter , also i would like to format the logs in logfmt format.
I was able to export the logs to a file but i am unable to find documentation which explains how to change the format of the logs.
Logs (also traces and metrics) seems must be exported in OTLP JSON format.

The data must be encoded according to the format specified in the OTLP JSON Encoding.
Only top-level objects, TracesData, MetricsData, and LogsData are supported.
Files must contain exactly one type of data: traces, metrics, or logs.
...
This is an example showing logs:
{"resourceLogs":[{"resource":{"attributes":[{"key":"resource-attr","value":{"stringValue":"resource-attr-val-1"}}]},"scopeLogs":[{"scope":{},"logRecords":[{"timeUnixNano":"1581452773000000789","severityNumber":9,"severityText":"Info","body":{"stringValue":"This is a log message"},"attributes":[{"key":"app","value":{"stringValue":"server"}},{"key":"instance_num","value":{"intValue":"1"}}],"droppedAttributesCount":1,"traceId":"08040201000000000000000000000000","spanId":"0102040800000000"},{"timeUnixNano":"1581452773000000789","severityNumber":9,"severityText":"Info","body":{"stringValue":"something happened"},"attributes":[{"key":"customer","value":{"stringValue":"acme"}},{"key":"env","value":{"stringValue":"dev"}}],"droppedAttributesCount":1,"traceId":"","spanId":""}]}]}]}


This is my current config:
    exporters:
        debug:
            verbosity: detailed
        file:
            path: /otel-data/otel-exporter.log
            format: json
            rotation:
                max_backups: 15
                max_megabytes: 50


